# Node.js NPM and Typescript Can't access class functions from test app

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, typescript, npm

I am writing a NPM package so I can re-use a class.  Package installs fine, can load the class, however I cannot access functions within the class.  I am using typescript which is then compiled into a JS class:

As an example, compiled output.

```
---------------------------------    
FILE ./node_modules/test/index.js
---------------------------------
class Test{
    constructor(){

    }

    hello(name){
            console.log("Hello " + name);
    }
}
module.exports.Test = Test;  // Note I have also tried module.exports = Test

---------------
FILE: ./test.js
---------------
var test = require('test');

console.log(test) // ok, object is defined.

test.hello('THERE');  // error

---------------
# node test.js


// Error
test.hello('Hello');
^

TypeError: test.hello is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Tony/test/index.js:6:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:1
```

Comment: for me, this is very basic about programming: class and instance.

Comment: @kai, Great response, good for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create an instance of your class to invoke the methods on it, right? So does:

```
var Test = require('test');
var test = new Test();
test.hello('THERE');
```

Work as expected?

If not, does the package.json in `./node_modules/test` have a `main` key that points to `index.js`?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways for you to implement:

- Class and Instance: if you're going to create any class object to extends, create new, etc, you must create new instance from the class `Test`:

  ```
   const Test = require('./test');
   const test = new Test();
   test.hello('Kai'); // 'Hello Kai';
  ```
- Static function: If you're just want to create a class which has it own `function`:

  ```
   class Test {
     constructor(){

     }

     static hello(name){
       console.log("Hello " + name);
     }
   }
   module.exports = Test;

    //test.js
   const Test = require('./test')
   Test.hello('Kai'); // 'Hello Kai';
  ```

> Static method calls are made directly to the class and are not callable on instances of the class. Static methods are often used to create utility functions.